# Sort columns in a CSV file with golang

Tags: csv, go

I have this go code that writes a csv file:

```
func GetCotacao(c *gin.Context) {
    var data models.Cotacao
    var response []models.Cotacao

    query, err := DB.Query(`SELECT 
    f.nome_fornecedor,
    p.nome_produto,
    ic.valor_unitario,
    c.data_cotacao
FROM fornecedor AS f 
INNER JOIN fornecedor_produto   AS fp   ON fp.id_fornecedor     = f.id_fornecedor
INNER JOIN produto              AS p    ON p.id_produto     = fp.id_produto 

INNER JOIN fornecedor_empresa   AS fe   ON fe.id_fornecedor = f.id_fornecedor
INNER JOIN empresa              AS e    ON e.id_empresa     = fe.id_empresa 
INNER JOIN cotacao              AS c    ON c.id_empresa     = e.id_empresa 

INNER JOIN item_cotacao         AS ic   ON ic.id_produto    = fp.id_produto 
AND ic.id_fornecedor    = fe.id_fornecedor 
AND ic.id_cotacao       = c.id_cotacao 
WHERE c.data_cotacao = '2023-08-17'`)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Erro ao buscar cotacao", err)
        c.Status(400)
        return
    }

    for query.Next() {
        if err := query.Scan(&data.NomeFornecedor, &data.NomeProduto, &data.ValorUnitario, &data.DataCotacao); err != nil {
            log.Println("Erro ao buscar cotacao")
        }
        response = append(response, data)

    }
    c.JSON(200, response)

    arquivo, err := os.Create("cotacoes.csv")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Erro ao criar arquivo CSV", err)
        c.Status(400)
        return
    }
    defer arquivo.Close()

    // Criar um escritor CSV
    escritorCSV := csv.NewWriter(arquivo)
    defer escritorCSV.Flush()

    for _, add := range response {
        linhaCSV := []string{add.NomeFornecedor}
        err = escritorCSV.Write(linhaCSV)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Erro ao escrever linha no CSV", err)
            c.Status(400)
            return
        }

    }

}
```

and i have more columns to write in this csv, for example:
I want data.ProductName to be in column B of my csv file (since I'm going to open the file in excel)

and i have more columns to write in this csv, for example:
I want data.ProductName to be in column B of my csv file (since I'm going to open the file in excel)
but I couldn't find an approach to do this

WHAT DID I TRY?

```
for _, add := range response {
        linhaCSV := []string{add.NomeFornecedor, add.NomeProduto}
        err = escritorCSV.Write(linhaCSV)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Erro ao escrever linha no CSV", err)
            c.Status(400)
            return
        }

    }
```

as you can see, I tried to add more parameters in my "lineCSV" but it put everything in the same line separated by commas, how can I put my add.ProductName parameter in separate columns? is this possible ?

edit:
this is my csv, see that it has commas after a certain part
after each comma it was supposed to be a column

[image]

edit 2

Thanks in advance for your attention.
as requested in the comments, below is my print of the .csv file opened in other editors

vscode:
[image]

notpad++
[image]

edit 3

[image]

I opened it in google sheets and the result came as expected, separated by columns, would the problem be the excel that is on my PC?

Comment: "but it put everything in the same line separated by commas" that's what a CSV file is. Can you provide a sample of the raw output (open it in a text editor). I'm guessing this is an [excel issue](https://superuser.com/q/238944/1594936).

Comment: @Brits I edited my question and put the print of the content of the file already open in excel

Comment: Your screenshot looks like it's from Excel (see the [link](https://superuser.com/q/238944/1594936) I included re an excel issue). I suspect that your Go code is outputting a valid CSV file; but Excel is not loading the file in the way you expect. Open the output in a text editor (whatever you are using to edit your Go code would probably work) and show us that.

Comment: Your Excel might use `;` as default field separator for CSV files, instead of `,`

Comment: @britânicos hello, thanks for the support. I edited my question as requested and put my open file in two more editors and the result is the same

Answer (score 1):

Your Go program is working as intended; it's producing a comma delimited file (a file containing fields separated by commas `,`). CSV is an abbreviation for "Comma-Separated Values"; you may think it's pretty obvious what this means but, unfortunately, this is not the case.

There is no standard that dictates how a CSV file should be formatted; there is an [RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt) but that specifically states that "it does not specify an Internet standard of any kind" (it really documents common usage).

Files separated by commas work well in countries, like the US and the UK, where decimal points are used (e.g. "123.01") but there are issues in [countries that use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator) commas for the same purpose (e.g. "123,01" - is the `01` a decimal or a separate column?)

Probably for this reason, in Excel, a CSV file is actually a file delimited by whatever is set as the ["list separator"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-5250ac4c-663c-47ce-937b-339e391393ba). This results in the situation where a "Comma-Separated Values" file is not, in fact, separated by commas! Try creating a file in Excel with multiple columns, save it as a `CSV` and then open the resulting file in a text editor (e.g. notepad++); you will find that the columns are not, in fact, separated with commas... (I am making some assumptions here, on my PC it would be comma seperated due to my locale).

If you were to send me the files produced by your application and I opened them in Excel the result would be what you are expecting (similar to your results with Google sheets - Excel would use the commas to separate the data into columns); however opening the same file on your computer does not have the same result (most likely because the "list separator" is set to `;` or something else).

The answers to the [superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/238944/how-to-force-excel-to-open-csv-files-with-data-arranged-in-columns) I linked in the comments provides a few suggested solutions; these include:

- Change the separator to whatever is set as the "list separator" on your computer.
- Using a Tab separated file instead of a comma separated file.
- Writing out `SEP=,` on the first line of the file
- Change the file extension to `.TXT` (excel will then ask you how to convert it when you open it)

None of these solutions are ideal because they will not work in all situations (e.g. opening the file in another application or on another computer may not work as expected). If you are targeting Excel (and other spreadsheets) then I'd suggest writing out a `.xlsx` file; this will open more consistently and you will avoid other potential issues such as:

- Date formats changing when you save the CSV
- Loss of leading 0's on things like customer numbers
- Large numbers (e.g. part numbers) being converted to scientific notation.

CSV files are good because they are very simple and will be read by a lot of applications; however different programs will handle them in different ways so the results may not always be what you expect.